# Scala insert into list at specific locations

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

This is the problem that I did solve, however being a total imperative Scala noob, I feel I found something totally not elegant. Any ideas of improvement appreciated.

```
val l1 = 4 :: 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: Nil // original list
val insert = List(88,99) // list I want to insert on certain places

// method that finds all indexes of a particular element in a particular list
def indexesOf(element:Any, inList:List[Any]) = {
        var indexes = List[Int]()
        for(i <- 0 until inList.length) {
                if(inList(i) == element) indexes = indexes :+ i
        }
        indexes
}


var indexes = indexesOf(4, l1) // get indexes where 4 appears in the original list

println(indexes)

var result = List[Any]()

// iterate through indexes and insert in front
for(i <- 0 until indexes.length) {
        var prev = if(i == 0) 0 else indexes(i-1)
        result = result ::: l1.slice(prev, indexes(i)) ::: insert
}
result = result ::: l1.drop(indexes.last) // append the last bit from original list

println(result)
```

I was thinking more elegant solution would be achievable with something like this, but that's just pure speculation.

```
var final:List[Any] = (0 /: indexes) {(final, i) => final ::: ins ::: l1.slice(i, indexes(i))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def insert[A](xs: List[A], extra: List[A])(p: A => Boolean) = {
  xs.map(x => if (p(x)) extra ::: List(x) else List(x)).flatten
}

scala> insert(List(4,1,2,3,4),List(88,99)){_ == 4}
res3: List[Int] = List(88, 99, 4, 1, 2, 3, 88, 99, 4)
```

---

Edit: explanation added.

Our goal here is to insert a list (called `extra`) in front of selected elements in another list (here called `xs`--commonly used for lists, as if one thing is `x` then lots of them must be the plural `xs`).  We want this to work on any type of list we might have, so we annotate it with the generic type `[A]`.

Which elements are candidates for insertion?  When writing the function, we don't know, so we provide a function that says true or false for each element (`p: A => Boolean`).

Now, for each element in the list `x`, we check--should we make the insertion (i.e. is `p(x)` true)?  If yes, we just build it: `extra ::: List(x)` is just the elements of `extra` followed by the single item `x`.  (It might be better to write this as `extra :+ x`--add the single item at the end.)  If no, we have only the single item, but we make it `List(x)` instead of just `x` because we want everything to have the same type.  So now, if we have something like

```
4 1 2 3 4
```

and our condition is that we insert `5 6` before `4`, we generate

```
List(5 6 4) List(1) List(2) List(3) List(5 6 4)
```

This is exactly what we want, except we have a list of lists.  To get rid of the inner lists and flatten everything into a single list, we just call `flatten`.

Comment: Work of art ;) What does the first [A] mean? What does _ mean?

Comment: The first `[A]` means that it is a generic method (it works on some type `A`; the later `A`s are referring to that same one).  `_` means "whatever the variable is"; it's a shortcut for `x => x == 4`.

Comment: `xs.map(..).flatten` can be written as `xs.flatMap(..)`.

Comment: @Landei - Indeed.  I no longer remember why I did it this way; maybe I thought it was clearer to explain?  I'll leave it as is, but your point is well taken.

Answer (score 10):

The flatten trick is cute, I wouldn't have thought of using `map` here myself. From my perspective this problem is a typical application for a fold, as you want go through the list and "collect" something (the result list). As we don't want our result list backwards, `foldRight` (a.k.a. `:\`) is here the right version:

```
def insert[A](xs: List[A], extra: List[A])(p: A => Boolean) = 
  xs.foldRight(List[A]())((x,xs) => if (p(x)) extra ::: (x :: xs) else x :: xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility, using `Seq#patch` to handle the actual inserts.  You need to foldRight so that later indices are handled first (inserts modify the indices of all elements after the insert, so it would be tricky otherwise).

```
def insert[A](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[A])(pred: A => Boolean) = {
  val positions = xs.zipWithIndex filter(x => pred(x._1)) map(_._2)
  positions.foldRight(xs) { (pos, xs) => xs patch (pos, ys, 0) }
}
```